# is a return from another component okay if it's fairly large?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that creates a canvas and another `useCanvas` component that holds state for certain events / draws on canvas.

My return on the useCanvas is fairly large with a lot of callbacks and data that is required. This a road to bad design? It feels wrong. I don't know a different way of designing this method to return  a much cleaner approach.

Here is an example:

```
const TheMouseAndCanvas = (props) => {
    const [ 
        someFun, 
        someData, 
        setFunState, 
        someOther, 
        setMoreState, 
        recordMouse, 
        itsFlying, 
        setItsNotFlying, 
        setFun1, 
        SetRandomSet, 
        isItHappening, 
        letTest, 
        SetThisFeelsWrong, 
        itIsWrong, 
        setTesterr, 
        // etc, maybe another 5 or more
    ] = useCanvas();

    const aFunction = (e) => {
        // do things with event and use returns useCanvas
    }  

    // more such functions as aFunction

    return (
        // a canvas with callbacks
    )
}
```

The return are just placed for example, and my app works exactly how I want it to and debugging/working it is easy, along with adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This a road to bad design?

Yes, for at least two reasons:

1. you need to remember the order of everything you are returning
2. refactoring would be painful and error prone

The issue is not that you have many utilities, is that you return these utilities as *array*, as opposite of a plain object.

```
const TheMouseAndCanvas = (props) => {
    const {
        someFun, 
        someData, 
        setFunState, 
        someOther, 
        setMoreState, 
        recordMouse, 
        itsFlying, 
        setItsNotFlying, 
        setFun1, 
        SetRandomSet, 
        isItHappening, 
        letTest, 
        SetThisFeelsWrong, 
        itIsWrong, 
        setTesterr, 
        // etc, maybe another 5 or more
    } = useCanvas();

    const aFunction = (e) => {
        // do things with event and use returns useCanvas
    }  

    // more such functions as aFunction

    return (
        // a canvas with callbacks
    )
}
```

With this approach, you don't need to remember where utilities are positioned in the returned *array*, all you need to remember is the utility name.

This gives you some advantage:

1. you can order utilities alphabetically, as example, keeping it easier to read through all of them
2. you never need to remember any order from a foreign callback

Strawberry on top, you can assign all methods at once to the canvas now:

```
const TheMouseAndCanvas = (props) => {
    const utils = useCanvas();

    const aFunction = (e) => {
        // do things with event and use returns useCanvas
    }  

    // more such functions as aFunction

    return Object.assign(canvas, utils);
}
```

I hope this reasons well to you.

Comment: This was excellent information, that strawberry you mentioned.. can you elaborate a little bit more on it in your answer? It seems extremely useful and Google searches don't seem to bring up much.

Comment: it was a *hint*, rather than a whole solution, but basically you have an object you can use to copy any utility to any other object, in this case the canvas, or you can pass it as `<Canvas {...utils} />` and have methods/props attached ... you have an object, you can do "*object things*" now, not so simple with an *array*.